# Select statement validating as true when no value selected?

Tags: form, validation

I have a plugin with record and model both setting required to true for a frontend form entry:

```
'fieldName' =>  array(AttributeType::Name, 'required' => true),
```

However it is still validating the select option even when there is no value so:

```
<select id="fieldName" name="fieldName">
    <option>--select one--</option>
```

or

```
<option value=''>--select one--</option>
```

Still validates as true.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting a minimum length:

```
'fieldName' =>  array(AttributeType::Name, 'minLength' => 1, 'required' => true),
```

Comment: cheers @carlcs that worked